# Fredholm operators and Compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ be an infinite  dimensional Banach space. How to prove that:
$A$ and $B$ are two Fredholm operator on $X$, if 
$\mathrm{index}(A)=\mathrm{index}(B)$, then there exists an invertible operator $C$ such that 
$A-BC$ is compact???

I know that if $T$ is a Fredholm operator with $\mathrm{index}(T)=0$ iff there exist  an invertible operator A and a compact operator $K$ such that $T=A+K$.